# isinstance() unexpectedly returning False

Tags: python, inheritance, exception, kubernetes

I am using the [kubernetes python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python/).  In the event that kubernetes isn't available when my code starts up, I would like to retry the connection.

When the client is unable to connect, it throws what appears to be a `urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError` exception, so I started with something like this:

```
import time
import urllib3

import kubernetes

kubernetes.config.load_kube_config()
api = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api()

while True:
    try:
        w = kubernetes.watch.Watch()
        for event in w.stream(api.list_pod_for_all_namespaces):
            print event
    except urllib3.exceptions.HTTPError:
        print('retrying in 1 second')
        time.sleep(1)
```

But that completely fails; it acts like there is no `except` statement and bails out with:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.122.140', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/pods?watch=True (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x2743110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I thought maybe I didn't understand inheritance as well as I thought, so I replace the above with:

```
except urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
    print('retrying in 1 second')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Which fails in the same way.  In an effort to figure out what was going on, I added a catch-all `except` and invoked pdb:

```
except Exception as err:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

And from the `pdb` prompt, we can see:

```
(Pdb) type(err)
<class 'urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError'>
```

...which looks fine, as does the mro:

```
(Pdb) import inspect
(Pdb) inspect.getmro(err.__class__)
(<class 'urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError'>, <class 'urllib3.exceptions.RequestError'>, <class 'urllib3.exceptions.PoolError'>, <class 'urllib3.exceptions.HTTPError'>, <type 'exceptions.Exception'>, <type 'exceptions.BaseException'>, <type 'object'>)
```

But despite all that:

```
(Pdb) isinstance(err, urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError)
False
```

And all the paths look reasonable:

```
(Pdb) urllib3.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.pyc'
(Pdb) kubernetes.client.rest.urllib3.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.pyc'
```

So...what the actual what is going on here?

**Update**

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testkube.py", line 13, in <module>
    for event in w.stream(api.list_pod_for_all_namespaces):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 116, in stream
    resp = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py", line 14368, in list_pod_for_all_namespaces
    (data) = self.list_pod_for_all_namespaces_with_http_info(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py", line 14464, in list_pod_for_all_namespaces_with_http_info
    collection_formats=collection_formats)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 335, in call_api
    _preload_content, _request_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 148, in __call_api
    _request_timeout=_request_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 371, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 250, in GET
    query_params=query_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 223, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 66, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 87, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 321, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.122.140', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/pods?watch=True (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x3d16110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace.

Comment: What happens if you import `urllib3` _after_ importing `kubernetes`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson changing the order of the imports doesn't appear to change the behavior.

Comment: @larsks Thanks. It was a long shot. I was wondering whether either kubernetes or one of its dependencies (e.g., requests) was monkeypatching urllib3.

Comment: Hm. It's not happening in a different thread or anything like that. It looks like you have multiple copies of the same class, almost as if a module got reloaded. You didn't reload any modules, did you?

Comment: @user2357112 I am simply running the code presented in this question (the code is in `testkube.py` and I am running `python testkube.py`).

Comment: There does seem to be something funky with my environment: if I create a clean virtualenv I cannot reproduce this behavior.  I don't mind "my environment is screwy" as an answer, but I would love to find a positive diagnostic for this issue.

Comment: Try running `python -v testkube.py` to turn on [import logging](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#id4) and see if it looks like any modules are getting initialized twice.

Comment: @user2357112 that produces some interesting but lengthy results.  I've put them [here](http://chunk.io/larsks/a514bf26a4af46e7985610b2cc0caa65) for now, although I would be happy to put an excerpt in the question. I see that there is a `requests.packages.urllib3` in the mix, which I assume is the source of the problem, although it's not clear to me exactly where this is happening.

Comment: @larsks: Looks like chunk.io is blocked here, supposedly for "potential malicious activity or other security reasons". Maybe Pastebin?

Comment: The line `import requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.pyc` is _very_ suspicious ...

Comment: That's coming from [here](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/packages.py). It's definitely suspicious, but I'm not yet seeing a way that it could be causing this issue - it doesn't seem to generate any duplicate module objects or reexecute class definitions, for example.

Comment: @user2357112 [here](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/Vw4vVeR0DBsbgyOulksV~w) is another link for the `python -v` output.

Comment: Hmm... that inner loop over `list(sys.modules)` in `request.packages` won't find submodules that haven't been loaded yet. That could cause problems. Might be dependent on package versions...

Comment: Older versions of `requests` initialize `requests.packages` differently, and on those versions, `requests.packages` *does* cause reloading of `urllib3.exceptions`. `requests.packages` *was* the culprit!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has an indirect dependency on the `requests` package, and the `requests` package has a strange submodule called `requests.packages`. This used to contain copied source code from a number of dependencies, including `urllib3`, but they stopped doing that. They wanted to keep `requests.packages` around for backward compatibility, though, so now they're doing something weird.

Instead of `requests.packages` including a complete copy of the `urllib3` source code, it now imports `urllib3` and sets `sys.modules['requests.packages.urllib3'] = urllib3`. Depending on the `requests` version, it may set a number of other `sys.modules` entries, too; for example, as of requests [2.18.4](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/v2.18.4/requests/packages.py), the source code does

```
for package in ('urllib3', 'idna', 'chardet'):
    locals()[package] = __import__(package)
    # This traversal is apparently necessary such that the identities are
    # preserved (requests.packages.urllib3.* is urllib3.*)
    for mod in list(sys.modules):
        if mod == package or mod.startswith(package + '.'):
            sys.modules['requests.packages.' + mod] = sys.modules[mod]
```

but in [2.17.0](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/v2.17.0/requests/packages.py), it does

```
import urllib3
sys.modules['requests.packages.urllib3'] = urllib3

import idna
sys.modules['requests.packages.idna'] = idna

import chardet
sys.modules['requests.packages.chardet'] = chardet
```

This code interacts badly with submodules of the imported packages. If some code tries to do `import requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions` and Python doesn't find a `sys.modules['requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions']` entry, Python will *recreate* the `urllib3.exceptions` module and set `urllib3.exceptions` and `sys.modules['requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions']` to the new module (but it won't touch `sys.modules['urllib3.exceptions']`. This will generate new copies of the classes involved, causing your error.

A related problem with the same cause was [reported](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4102) back in May, leading to the new code shown in 2.18.4. 2.18.4 shouldn't cause the specific problems you're seeing, but it's still fragile, because if any submodules of `urllib3` aren't yet loaded at the time `requests.packages` screws with `sys.modules`, those submodules will exhibit the same problems you've seen today.

Comment: Thank you for your help figuring that out!  I was mystified.