# A module imported in a packages __init__.py is not dot accessible

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

This may be python's desired behavior, but I find it puzzling nonetheless -

I have the following file structure:

```
repo/
    foo/
        __init__.py
        foo/
            bar.py
```

where `__init__.py` is the following:

```
from .foo import bar
```

When I enter a python interpreter from within `repo/`, I am able to import `bar` like so:

```
>>> from foo import bar
>>> bar
<module 'foo.foo.bar' from '.../repo/foo/foo/bar.py'>
```

Great! However, the following does not work:

```
>>> import foo.bar as foobar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo.bar'
```

Perhaps I lack an understanding of how python's import statement works, but I would very much like to be able import as I showed above. If this is desired behavior, does anyone know of a workaround? Perhaps I can change something in `__init__.py`?

Out of concern for naming caveats, I have also tested this with the following file structure:

```
repo/
    foo/
        __init__.py
        baz/
            bar.py
```

... and I got the same result

I've tested this in python 3.6.2 and 3.6.6 on linux and macOS. I also saw the same behavior in python 2.7.13 (where, of course, I added an `__init__.py` into the lower `foo/` directory.

If I am unable to make this style of import work, `repo/` will have to undergo a bit of refactoring. Help me prevent this!

Comment: Don't you mean `import foo.foo.bar as foobar` as you have 2 folders called 'foo'

Comment: I was hoping that my `__init__.py` in the higher `foo/` would enable me to omit the second foo in my import statement.

Comment: Yea, that name has to be the name of a module. There is no module with the name `foo.bar`, although the `foo` module has an attribute `bar` which is a reference to the module named `foo.foo.bar`. how about `from foo import bar as foobar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual name of the module you want to import is `foo.foo.bar`. Your `from .foo import bar` in `__init__.py` doesn't change that.

`from foo import bar` will give you the `bar` attribute of the `foo` module object, and that actually is the module you want, thanks to that line in your `__init__.py`. `import foo.bar` needs an actual `foo.bar` module, though. If it does not find an entry for that name in `sys.modules`, it will throw an error. Do not be tempted to mess with `sys.modules` to "fix" this; that leads to [really confusing double-import bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715586/isinstance-unexpectedly-returning-false).

Comment: Oof, I guess I'll let it go. Though this feels somewhat inconsistent to me - since `.` is typically used to access attributes in python, I would expect it to do the same in an import statement. What you're saying is that the "spam.eggs" in `import spam.eggs` is not accessing the attribute `eggs` of package `spam`, but rather, it is simply the name of the module?