# Handling nested ConnectionError exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running a script that communicates with a Rest API. Occasionally it's returning an exception that also returns `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:` for two additional exceptions. I'm trying to handle it using try/except blocks, but despite importing all three exceptions and coding for them in the blocks the script still fails.

The three exceptions are `http.client.RemoteDisconnected`, `urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError` and `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`.

So my import code is:

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from http.client import RemoteDisconnected
from urllib3.exceptions import ProtocolError
```

My IDE recognizes the exceptions as imported, so that's probably fine. My except code is:

```
try
    [the thing]
except (InternalError, ConnectionError, RemoteDisconnected, ProtocolError) as e:
    self.lg.log(str(e) + ' ' + str(e.__traceback__) + " Some sort of connection or 
            internal error occured")
```

I have another exception on the same block (`InternalError`) and that one seems to handle fine.

The Traceback is really long but I'm not sure which parts are most important, so here's the whole thing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rominus/PycharmProjects/Binance/Skitter_trade_test.py", line 55, in <module>
    bintime = int(client.time()['serverTime'])
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\api.py", line 98, in time
    return self._get('v1/time')
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\api.py", line 62, in _get
    return self._request(endpoint, param, "get")
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\api.py", line 40, in _request
    r = getattr(self.session, http_method)(BinanceAPI.API_URL + endpoint, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 525, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rominus\PycharmProjects\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 495, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

Comment: What version of `requests` are you on? This kind of reminds me of [another bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715586/isinstance-unexpectedly-returning-false) in specific versions of `requests`.

Comment: I'm using `requests` 2.19.1

Comment: Aside from that, are you sure you're importing `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` in the file that needs it? It's likely you're using the wrong `ConnectionError`; there's a built-in exception type with the same name.

Comment: I'm definitely importing it to the right file. How would I deal with the name duplication?

Comment: @user2357112 (responded to your questions in comments but didn't @ you like I should've)

Comment: you could catch that exception and print its type: `except Exception as e: print(type(e))`