# How can I add a submodule to a module at import time?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a module object `foo` and I want to dynamically add module `bar` to it at import time. How can I accomplish that?

Work done so far:

I've been trying to accomplish this by adding `bar` to the `__init__.py` file for `foo`.

```
bar = function_that_returns_module_bar()
```

This allows me to do

```
from foo import bar
```

However the following fails

```
import foo.bar
```

Furthermore, let's say `bar` has a submodule `baz`, I'm also unable to do

```
from foo.bar import baz
```

Is what I'm describing possible?

Comment: The is in fact what the `os` module does, which enables you to use the "sub-module" `os.path` after only importing `os`.

Comment: It's also a bad idea, and nothing else in the standard library has done the same thing since `os.path`, even when functionality is os-dependent.

Comment: Especially with submodules, doing this can lead to ["evil twin" classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715586/isinstance-unexpectedly-returning-false) and other nastiness.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the modules inside `__init__.py`

`foo/__init__.py`:

```py
from foo import bar
```

`foo/bar/__init__.py`:

```py
from foo.bar import baz
```

`foo/bar/baz/__init__.py`:

```py
def g():
    return "Hello"
```

Then you can use the modules as follows:

```py
from foo.bar import baz

baz.g()
```

EDIT:

If you don't really have the directories in your filesystem, then you have to manually add the modules to sys.modules dictionary (since when you just declare a variable on a module it is not added to sys.modules dictionary):

```py
import sys

sys.modules['foo.bar'] = function_that_returns_bar_module()
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without import statements? I have a function that returns the module object. I’m not actually capable of doing this via imports. Since I have to work with the module returned by the function.

Comment: I've added such a scenario.