# Not able to create shortcut for sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I entered the following code:

```python
import sklearn
import sklearn as sk
import sklearn.preprocessing as skl

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer 
from sk.preprocessing import Imputer
from skl import Imputer
```

The part which reads; `from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer` gets executed normally.

However, when I run `from sk.preprocessing import Imputer`, I get the following error:

```
from sk.preprocessing import Imputer
Traceback (most recent call last):`
File "<ipython-input-84-fc12144914d1>", line 1, in <module>`
    from sk.preprocessing import Imputer`
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sk'`
```

And `from skl import Imputer` yields the following:

```
from skl import Imputer`
Traceback (most recent call last):`
File "<ipython-input-85-1e925587d122>", line 1, in <module>`
        from skl import Imputer`
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skl'`
```

Why am I not able to create a shortcut for the Library?

Comment: You cannot use aliases for import. You can use them only for declaring. Something like `imputer = skl.Imputer()` or `imputer = sk.preprocessing.Imputer()` should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import modules using an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459939/import-modules-using-an-alias)

Answer (score 0):

Because it is wrong to do so. The right way do do it is as you have written already.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
```

the `__init__.py`  in the preprocessing [directory](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/preprocessing/__init__.py) of `sklearn` defines the possible imports from that level.

The below is a valid aliasing and i think is what you are looking for.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer as imp
```